# Dragging the button navigates to the next page how I can write the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net

```
    <a draggable="true" class="user" id="leonardo" ondragstart="dragUser(this, event)" aria-selected="undefined">
    IPD</a>
```

dragging the button it will navigate the next page how i can write the code?

Answer (score 0):

To navigate

```
function dragUser(el){
window.loaction ='write the url here';
}
```

This is stop navigation

add `href="javascript:void(0)"`

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" draggable="true" class="user" id="leonardo" ondragstart="dragUser(this, event)" aria-selected="undefined">
    IPD</a>
```